# Sparse Blas on Mac OS Fortran

Tags: macos, fortran, sparse-matrix, blas

I want to use Sparse Blas operations on Mac OS in Fortran

Here is the programm

```
PROGRAM F95_EX

IMPLICIT NONE 
INTEGER NMAX, NNZ 
PARAMETER (NMAX=4, NNZ=6) 
INTEGER i,n,a,istat
INTEGER,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE :: indx,jndx 
DOUBLE PRECISION,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE :: val,x,y

ALLOCATE(val(NNZ),x(NMAX),y(NMAX),indx(NNZ),jndx(NNZ))

indx = (/1,2,2,3,4,4/) jndx = (/1,2,4,3,1,4/)

val =(/1.1,2.2,2.4,3.3,4.1,4.4/) N = NMAX

CALL  duscr_begin(n,n,a,istat)


END PROGRAM F95_EX
```

What libraries should I include and what flags should I pass to gfortran to compile this file? I know that there should be a sparse_blas library, but how can I install it on Mac as it is not in Accelerate framework?

Comment: I would have my env prepared from the sources - https://www.owsiak.org/building-opencoarrays-on-macos-everything-from-the-sources-gcc-8-3-0/ On top of that, I would have blas compiled from the sources as well. But, it might be you will get better answers, pointing to `brew` or something like that.